# Regular expression for this pattern

Tags: java, regex

I want a regular expression for a patterns which

1) String can contain atleast one '/' and one digit(/2/) or digits with spaces(//232 232/) or only one space(/// ////)

2) text is not allowed

```
**valid inputs:**

/1 323////
///////323 3232
//4343//4343
3/

**Invalid inputs:**

/////
121
///////3434dsds344//
//dsd///232
```

I have used `^/*(?:\\d[\\d ]*/*)*$` but this is failing for few of valid inputs like `232/////232`

Can any one help ?

Comment: Can you explain this a little more clearly.  It's not clear what the specification is.

Comment: @SachinKainth *Atleast one `/` and one digit, space is optional but allowed, text is not allowed*.

Comment: Try removing the ^ from the start. This implies that / should be the first character.

Comment: After edit, it's not clear anymore if the space is optional. And was does mean "in between them "? Must the space be at specific positions ?

Comment: Does "digits with spaces" mean there can be more than one, or exactly one space?

Comment: 1 space after number but like this //3232 3232 3232////32323 323/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one should work :

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*\/)^[\d\/ ]+$
```

Comment: I like regular expressions, they look like alien signs on a cornfield but are so powerful,

Answer (score 0):

A simple alternation should suffice:

```
^(?:\d+ */+|/+ *\d+)[\d/ ]*$
```